# How can I remove this bottom margin on my UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITableView as one of the (two) view controllers of a UITabBarController. **The tab bar on the UITabBarController is hidden** though, but this suits our UX because we wanted the user to be able to switch back and forth between two main screens.

The problem we're seeing, is a margin at the bottom of each of the UITableViewControllers inside the UITabBarController—I assume this is because the tab bar controller expects the tab bar to be visible.

The "Load more" button is the last UITableViewCell in the UITableView.

As you can see in the screenshot below, there's a bottom-margin between the scroll-bar on the right and the actual bottom of the UITableView.

How can I get rid of this margin, and reduce all of the white (grey) space between the last cell and the bottom of the view?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Storyboard -> Attribute inspector

ViewController Section -> Layout -> Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the storyboard, and uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the ViewController that contains the tableviews.